# jquery mobile prevent multiple handlers firing from single event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've set up a multi-page html document, with sliding transitions between pages intended to be fired when the user swipes tabs on the left or right side of the page. The info on which pages the tabs should swipe to is embedded in  attributes at the top of each page div.

The initial swipe works fine once, but each successive swipe seems to multiply up, so the next wipe moves up by two pages, the following one by four, and so on. So far as I can figure out, the Init function is getting called correctly once for each page, but the swipes are being multiplied.

Reading around, I suspect the answer is to unbind the swipe event the moment it fires once, and rebind it once the page transition is complete, but I can't for the life of me figure out how... I'm a newb at all this, so a simple explanation would be great!

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="intro1" class="page" data-rightTarget= "#intro2" data-
leftTarget= "#intro1">

        <script>
        $("body").on('pageshow', "#intro1", function() {
                          InitIntroSliders ();
                          });
        </script>
...

</div><!-- /intro1 -->  

<div data-role="page" id="intro2" class="page" data-rightTarget= "#intro3" data-     
leftTarget= "#intro1">

        <script>
        $("body").on('pageshow', "#intro2", function() {
                        InitIntroSliders ();
                        });
        </script>
...

 </div><!-- /intro2 -->
```

... etc. (It seems I have to put the scripts in the div for each page rather than the overall Head in order to get them to reload the Initialisation script on each new page).

And here's the jQuery:

```
function InitIntroSliders (){

$(document).on("swipeleft","#righttab", function(){
                var rightTarget = $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-rightTarget");
                $.mobile.changePage($(rightTarget), {transition: 'slide'});
//$(document).off("swipeleft", "#righttab", function());
                });

$(document).on("swiperight","#lefttab", function(){
                var leftTarget = $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-leftTarget");
                $.mobile.changePage($(leftTarget), {transition: 'slide', reverse: 
                'true'});
//$(document).off("swiperight", "#lefttab", function());
                });
}
```

I've tried adding in the commented-out lines to turn the binding off, but all that seems to do is bring the whole thing grinding to a halt. Any ideas greatly appreciated! Giles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to bind your handlers on each `pageShow`.